# pl/sql package/procedure no data found error

Tags: plsql

I'm facing no data found error when I'm executing a procedure. But the row is actually present in table. Please help me in this.

```
**Code**
*CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY SCOTT."TRUNC_ANALYZE_PKG"
as
PROCEDURE TRUNC_TABLE(v_owner in varchar2, v_tab_name IN VARCHAR2) AS
    t_owner varchar2(30) ;
BEGIN
   -- Truncate only EMP tables
   SELECT     owner
     INTO     t_owner
     FROM     all_tables
    WHERE     table_name = upper(v_tab_name)
                and owner in ('EMP') ;
execute immediate ('TRUNCATE TABLE EMP.'||upper(v_tab_name)) ;
  EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
      THEN
              RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20023, v_tab_name||' Schema name or Table name is not valid. '||SUBSTR(SQLERRM,1,500));
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
              RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20023, v_tab_name||SUBSTR(SQLERRM,1,500));
END TRUNC_TABLE;
PROCEDURE ANALYZE_TABLE(v_owner in varchar2, v_tab_name IN VARCHAR2) AS
 v_tab_owner varchar2(30) := upper(v_owner) ;
 v_tab_name2 varchar2(30) := upper(v_tab_name) ;
BEGIN
dbms_ddl.analyze_object('TABLE',v_tab_owner,v_tab_name2,'ESTIMATE','',20,'');
exception
   when others then
      /* Raise the error to the calling proc id
required. */
      raise;
END ANALYZE_TABLE;
END TRUNC_ANALYZE_PKG;
/*
```

**Error Message:**

```
SQL> exec SCOTT.DBA_PKG.TRUNC_TABLE('EMP','EMPLOYEE');
BEGIN DBA_PKG.TRUNC_TABLE('EMP','EMPLOYEE'); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20023: STG_FIRMINFO Schema name or Table name is not valid. ORA-01403: no
data found
ORA-06512: at "EIB_USER.DBA_PKG", line 21
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

But actually EMPLOYEE table is present in all_tables. I'm not able to crack why this exception is caught. Please help me in this.

Thanks,
Poova.

Comment: What user are you logged in as?  And does user SCOTT have SELECT access to the ALL_TABLES view?

Comment: Also, why is the error message prefixed with `STG_FIRMINFO` instead of `EMPLOYEE`?  It appears some code in the package `EIB_USER.DBA_PKG` is trying to truncate the `STG_FIRMINFO` table instead of `EMP.EMPLOYEE`.

Comment: yes..SCOTT is having access to ALL_TABLES. And I'm sorry I tried to replace my actual schema name and table name using scott and employee table but I mistakenly posted my actual error message.

Comment: SELECT     owner FROM     all_tables WHERE     table_name = upper('EMPLOYEE') and owner in ('EMP') ; This query is working outside of package. This is returning EMP as result. But inside the package it is not working. Pls help me in identifying the root cause. A public synonym has been created for this package. Will that be a problem

Answer (score 0):

when you **select in procedure**:
   `select count(*) into xx from all_tables`: xx is a number of table that you can select.

but when you **select in sql developer**:
   `select count(*) into xx from all_tables`: xx is number of all tables in your database.

thus, in your case you have to `grant "select any table" to scott`